# Assistance on creating algorithm for creating box around arc

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles

I am looking for some assistance on creating an algorithm that is able to calculate a bounding box for an arc. Typically, this would be a simple problem. However, I am required to have one of the edges of the box to be the line that connects the starting point and the ending point of the arc.

I am having difficulty in developing an algorithm that is able to compute the additional two points of the rectangle.

Here is a picture of what I am attempting to calculate:

[image: arc box]

The two purple dots, I need to develop an algorithm that will determine these two locations. The green dots are the known points that can be inputs. Additionally, I do know the radius and the center of the arc.

I would need the algorithm to handle the different cases for when line AB is vertical, has a + slope, and has a - slope.

I have been considering a few directions. For example, I know that the line through point E is parallel to line AB. Since it is parallel, that means they will have the same slopes and the line from point A to the purple point is perpendicular to this line. I can then consider the intersection point of the line through E and this perpendicular line.

This method seems messy because then I would need to consider the cases for when the slope of line AB is infinite and 0. I am wondering if there is some algorithm that could account for that automatically (or not even consider the slope at all for line AB)

Comment: Perhaps read up about matrices

Comment: Which of the points do you know?  How do you determine the distance CE?  This appears to be straightforward analytic geometry.  Handling infinite slope is a simple `if` check.

Comment: The points that are green are known values. Points A, B, C, D, and E. I do not what to go into details on how I know Point E but basically, Point E is an offset of Point D. I calculated the Angle BCD and I know angle BCE will be the same. I used the equation for a circle to calculate the X and Y points of point E since point E is on a concentric circle.

Comment: I do think that it is a straightforward analytic geometry but I feel like I am missing something

Comment: What type of arc is it? The kind of bounding box you described does not exist if the tangent at A or B makes an obtuse angle with AB (unless the box can extend beyond A and B).

Comment: This is a circular arc whose arc angle will never exceed 180°

Comment: It's easy enough to compute the apex of the arc. That will serve as the midpoint of the opposite edge to AB; the box follows from there.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this over on http://math.stackexchange.com. Once you have the mathematics nailed down, turning that into an algorithm will be relatively easy. One other question, did you mean "when line AB is horizontal" (as per your example) rather than vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You claim to know points `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and that the amplitude of the sustaining angle of the circular arc does not exceed 180° (semi circle).
Let `P1`, and `P2`, the two points that complement the bounding box - (in the drawing, `P1` is the purple point above `A`, and `P2` the one above `B`).

#### Using vectors:

`E-C = vector perpendicular to segment AB', i/e subtract C from E; its magnitude is equal to the distance EC`.
`P1 = A + (E-C)`
`P2 = B + (E-C)`

Bounding Box = Rectangle `A`, `P1`, `P2`, `B`

If you need a closer fit, you can replace `vector (E-C)` with `vector (D-C)` to place the bounding segment `P1P2` tangent to `D`